# PC starts but doesn't boot, no peripherals working, no network, won't turn off

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, power-supply

Moments ago I was using my PC normally and I plugged in my phone. I was browsing its files, clicked on the option to sort them by date, and then the display, network and peripherals got disconnected and the PC begun making a loud fan noise and became unresponsive. I tried to power it off on the button but it didn't work. I had to unplug it.
I let it rest for a while and tried again: same thing. Now it starts and doesn't even boot, just hangs in that locked state. There is a rattling noise coming from the fan and the power light flickers.

I've tried:

- disconnected all peripherals and tried to boot
- removed new RAM and put back old one (I upgraded recently)
- replaced motherboard battery with a new one
- checked the monitor

None of this did anything.

Recently (about a couple of months ago) I cleaned up this PC (ASUS M11BB-US001O) and installed new RAM (kingston KVR16N11K2 8MB *2, 16TB HDD Exos X16 7200 RPM 512e/4Kn SATA 6Gb/s). It was working perfectly well until today. The OS is debian 11. The disk is encrypted with LUKs (idk if this is relevant).

Specs: https://www.manua.ls/asus/m11bb/specifications

Until a few months ago the PC was just sitting there unused gathering dust. I got it circa 2017 and until the upgrades a couple of months ago I hadn't touched the hardware.
Could it be the power supply?

To summarize:

- The PC starts when I press the button but doesn't boot. There is no display.
- The tray doesn't work, nor do any of the peripherals nor does it connect to the network
- The fan works and the light turns on. The light flickers.
- The noise it makes is normal booting noise. Not excessive or anything
- There is a rattling noise coming from the fan that is connected to the power supply. This isn't new; I noticed it the first time when I upgraded the PC. It didn't seem to cause trouble so I just ignored it.
- I did notice one major difference: before, as it booted, I could hear the new HD make some noise as it was being read. Now, nothing.

Help?

Comment: Do two things:   Boot with a bootable USB Key.  Then (assuming it boots and displays), test the hard drive for errors.  Use memtest86.exe (need to make a bootable USB with Rufus) and test memory.

Comment: @John I can't even access the BIOS. It doesn't get that far.

Comment: If the is the case, the motherboard is bad.

Comment: @John how do you know that's the issue and not the PSU?

Comment: It could the PSU.   You may need to get service at this point.

Comment: @John I ordered a new PSU. I will try it out and when I do I will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the PSU. I got it replaced and now works like a charm.